# Issue with Get message from ActiveMQ Queue

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ REST APIS to POST and GET the messages from queue.
POST is always working but GET API is not working all the time. It is giving 204 No content messages but there are message in Queue.

Am not able understand why it is giving like this. am i using wrong API to read the message, can any one help me out please.

POST API:
http://localhost:8161/api/message/TEST?type=queue&clientId=test

GET API:
http://localhost:8161/api/message/TEST?readTimeout=100&type=queue&clientId=consumerA&oneShot=true

Comment: Followed this http://activemq.apache.org/ and trying through rest client

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file should have imported jetty.xml in the activemq.xml file. jetty.xml file has configured all the rest endpoints baseurl.

Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details

```
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - post the actual code instead.